# System of non-interacting particles in magnetic field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, magnetic-fields

> An ensemble of non-interacting spin particles is in contact with a heat bath at temperature $T$, and is subjected to an external magnetic field. Each particle can be in one of the two quantum states of energies $ \pm \epsilon_0$. If the mean energy per particle is $-\frac{\epsilon_0}{2}$ , then the free energy per particle is:
>
> 1. $-2\epsilon_0 \frac{\ln{\frac{4}{\sqrt{3}}}}{\ln{3}}$
> 2. $-\epsilon_0 \ln(\frac{3}{2})$
> 3. $-\epsilon_0 \frac{\ln2}{\ln3}$
> 4. $-2\epsilon_0 \ln2$

I have tried in the following methods:

1. The mean energy per particle is $-\epsilon_0/2$.
   So the total energy of the system of $N$ particles is $-N\epsilon_0/2$. And total number of micro-states is $2^N$. 
   Then the free energy $F=E-TS=-N\epsilon_0/2-Nk_BT\ln2$. Hence free energy per particle is $f=F/N=-\epsilon_0/2-k_BT\ln2$.
2. The partition function of the system is $Z=[e^{\beta \epsilon_0}+e^{-\beta \epsilon_0}]^N$.
   So the free energy per particle $f=F/N=-k_BT \ln[2\cosh(\beta \epsilon_0)]$.

But none of that yields the answer. Could you please explain where is the fault?

Answer (score 2):

Here's what's wrong with your two methods.

1. The $2^N$ microstates do not all have the same energy. Since you are thinking in terms of a microcanonical distribution for this method, you want to only count the states with total energy $E$. But really since this is in contact with a heat bath you should be thinking in terms of a canonical distribution like your second method (although counting the states with energy equal to the average total energy should be pretty close to this).
2. **Are you sure this isn't one of the answers?** The temperature is not a free parameter if you have fixed the average energy. In terms of the partition function the average energy is equal to
   $$-N\frac{\epsilon}{2}=-\frac{\partial}{\partial\beta}\ln Z.$$
   This fixes $\beta$ in terms of $\epsilon$.

Comment: Actually I was curious and tried it, and the "pretty close" I said for method 1 is equivalent to dropping the $O(\ln N)$ corrections to Stirling's approximation. So both of these methods done correctly (using $\ln N! = N \ln N - N$ in the 1st) give the right answer.

Comment: It is a question from [Joint CSIR UGC NET 2015 December Exam (Physics paper, question no: 60)](http://csirhrdg.res.in/phyA_Dec2015.pdf) and the correct answer is given to be the option 1. @octonion

Comment: @SwarnadeepSeth If you read carefully what octonion wrote, you will obtain the correct answer (which is 1).